# Does V_EN have to be equal to V_IN to be "high" on an step-up dc-dc converter? (MT3608 on/off control)

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter, step-up

I have an [MT3608 step-up converter<sup>[PDF]</sup>](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf), that I'm using to power a small fan (DC 12V 0.1A) with a DC 5V (4A max) power supply.
On my board V_EN and V_IN are soldered together ex factory, meaning it'll step-up if V_IN is connected.

Currently I'm using a RaspberryPi GPIO port (0V⭤3.3V with 50mA max.) over a [5V relay board (with optocoupler)](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001022991036.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.333b4c4dFCZjch) to apply the 5V to the MT3608 to turn the fan on and off... but this may be overkill.

My question is: Can I unsolder the V_EN from the V_IN and connect it directly to the GPIO port? Or are 3.3V too little (or have to be equal to V_IN for "on")?
And also: If this *is* ok, is the  current maximum of 50mA not enough for that?

[image: Circuit V_EN=0V/3.3V and V_IN=5V]

Comment: The information you're looking for is right in the data sheet and called "EN Input High Voltage".That's 1.5V, so a 3.3V input is fine.

Comment: @asdfex So, the max. current of 50mA is also ok?

Comment: Yes, typically a few uA only. Although this datasheet doesn't specify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data sheet has this table: -

[image]

So, given that you also have a 5 volt supply in your schematic, you'll be fine with 3.3 volt logic levels.

Comment: I saw this, but the fact that it says `Vin=Ven=...` at the top and my Ven current limit unsettled me. I only do electronics very rarely, so I wanted to be sure before I fry my RasPi. Thank you very much!

Comment: @NiklasE. The EN input will be high impedance so very little current will flow. However, if there's any chance that the 5 volts can be reset but the 3.3 volts keep running, I'd put a 10 kohm resistor in series from the GPIO.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. This is a very good idea; I will do that! Thank you again.